M365 Graph API script Error 404 when running but works fine when debugging
I'm running into an issue with a powershell script using Microsoft Graph API commands to create user accounts in M365.
It's strange because it wasn't having any issues until fairly recent. Basically, when I run it without debugging, it fails with an Error 404, but if I debug it and step through the function where it fails, it works perfectly fine. I can't understand why it wouldn't have any problems if I'm manually stepping through the code, unless it needs longer delays between REST calls but I have many 500ms pauses through out my script to slowdown the output.
This started last month, before then it would always hang for 3-5 seconds while adding the Auth Phone. It was a noticeably long pause, but only when adding the Auth Phone

It's specifically the add Authentication Phone, and Manager API calls that cause it to break. I have the same code used for a different tenant that excludes the Auth Phone and Manger and has no problems.
I'm using the same function call for all the API requests to create the user, add groups, and add licenses and none of those functions have any problem.
function Perform-RESTcall {
    
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$uri,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$method,
        [switch]$upn, # to handle latin letters for UPN
        $body # JSON body
    )

    $headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $($global:my_access_token)"; "ConsistencyLevel"="eventual"; Accept = "application/json"}
    $contentType = 'application/json'
    if ($upn) {
        $contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
    return (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Method $method -body $body)
}

# this is the URI and JSON i'm sending to Perform-RESTcall function
$addPhoneURI = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/'+$userCreationDetails.id+'/authentication/phoneMethods'

$phoneJson = @{
    phoneNumber = '8055552222'
    phoneType = 'mobile'
} | ConvertTo-Json


$phoneSr = Perform-RESTcall -uri $addPhoneURI -method "Post" $phoneJson

I'm completely stumped why it would fail to run but debug fine.

The error 404 indicates that the user isn't created yet when you're trying to add the phone method. Entra user create operation involves a sync update due to the distributed architecture of the service.
You may need to add a delay or a check to ensure the user is created before trying to add the phone method.
You check logic should have an exponential backoff or something that wraps around checking if the user is created. A delay of 5 seconds is also okay but may add huge delays when making several requests.
